# How to suppress all the print info from the Python Script?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there an easy way to suppress all the print info from the python script globally ?

Have a scenario where I had put lot of print info in the script for debug purpose, but when the user runs I don't want the script to print all the infos.

So only when I pass a command line argument like debug=1 or something like that, the print needs to provide the info else it shouldn't print.

Tried simply like,

```
if sys.argv[1]:
  debug=1
else:
  debug=0

if debug:
  print "Enabled debugging"
```

But for this I need to include the if condition everywhere, instead is there any easy way to shutdown the print info globally ? Share in your comments.

Thanks

Comment: You should consider using logging module

Answer (score 5):

You will have to redirect stdout to /dev/null.
Below is the OS agnostic way of doing it.

```
import os
import sys
f = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sys.stdout = f
```

Comment: Might want to explain what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

This is why you should use the built-in [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) library rather than writing print statements everywhere.

With that, you can call `logger.debug()` wherever you need to, and configure at application level whether or not the debug logs are actually output.

Comment: I can try changing.. if I use logging.debug("I am using debug option"), how do I control the verbosity from the command line ?

Comment: There are bunch of tutorial on the logging, you should refer them.