# How do I suppress outputs from the TensorFlow Object Detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am using the TensorFlow Object Detection API. I trained a model and extracted a graph, but during inference I get messages that seem like prints of the graph layers and training parameters. Here's a taste:

> Optimizing fused batch norm node name: "SecondStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_5c/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm"
>
> op: "FusedBatchNorm"
>
> input: "SecondStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_5c/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/Conv2D"
>
> input: "SecondStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_5c/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma"
>
> input: "SecondStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_5c/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/beta"
>   input:
>   "SecondStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_5c/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_mean"
>
> input:
>   "SecondStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_5c/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_variance"
>
> device: "/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"
>
> attr {   key:
>   "T"   value {
>       type: DT_FLOAT   } }
>
> attr {   key: "data_format"   value {
>       s: "NHWC"   } }

And many more.

How can I suppress these messages?

I already tried `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']` and `tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)`. They do not suppress the object detection API messages.

My inference code is similar to the one presented [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb). Here is my code:

```
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')


images = glob.glob(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Get handles to input and output tensors
        ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
        all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
        tensor_dict = {}

    for key in ['num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores', 'detection_classes']:
        tensor_name = key + ':0'

        if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
            tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(tensor_name)

    image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

    # Run inference
    for image_filename in images:
        image = nd.imread(image_filename)
        image = imresize(image, 50)

        output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict, feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})

        # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate
        boxes = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
        plt.imshow(image)
        shape = image.shape
        for i in range(int(output_dict['num_detections'][0])):
            box_y = boxes[i][0]*shape[0]
            box_x = boxes[i][1]*shape[1]
            box_h = (boxes[i][2] - boxes[i][0])*shape[0]
            box_w = (boxes[i][3] - boxes[i][1])*shape[1]

            ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((box_x, box_y), box_w, box_h, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none'))
        fig.show()
        plt.waitforbuttonpress()
        ax.clear()
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you found the solution ? btw, these logs aren't displayes in jupyter, but they are when called from shell

Comment: Sadly I did not find any solution, and this is no longer relevant so I stopped looking for one. Coming back to this question now, I think I should have tried a different approach: suppressing the prints via Python and not TensorFlow. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597102/how-to-suppress-all-the-print-info-from-the-python-script/39597191